# page break in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasper report 3.7.6 in primefaces.I have a list of students from class 1 to class 5 in ascending order according to class and want to print that list.My jasper print must start from new page if the student is from different class.How this can be addressed in jasper report? My jasper code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="AttendenceSheet" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="2.257895720215118"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="ExamDate" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="rollNo" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[rollNo]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="examDateNp" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[examDateNp]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="sn" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[sn]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="class" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[room]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="sn_1" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{sn}]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="73" y="21" width="146" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Student Seat Plan Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="411" y="53" width="68" height="13"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Exam Date :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="480" y="53" width="70" height="13"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{ExamDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="4" y="53" width="52" height="13"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Class:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="60" y="53" width="100" height="13"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{class}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="23">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="22" width="556" height="1" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="23"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="0" width="1" height="23"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="24" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="2" width="22" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[SN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="122" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="27" y="2" width="95" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Roll No.]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="272" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="130" y="0" width="141" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Student Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="281" y="0" width="154" height="21"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Signature]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="435" y="0" width="1" height="22"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="436" y="0" width="118" height="21"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Remarks]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="18">
            <line>
                <reportElement x="122" y="0" width="1" height="18"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="272" y="0" width="1" height="18"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="28" y="-1" width="78" height="18"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{rollNo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="435" y="0" width="1" height="18"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="3" y="-1" width="19" height="18"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{sn}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="0" width="1" height="18"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="24" y="0" width="1" height="18"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="18"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="17" width="556" height="1"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="127" y="-1" width="145" height="18"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You group on class and then you use the property isStartNewPage="true" on groupHeader. Please pass some of your relevant jrxml code and we can answer your question more precisely..

Comment: do you like to break  page in a list or table component or are you using detail band with subreports?

Comment: on start of student from different class in list print should start from new page.

Answer (score 0):

The "normal way" to achieve this is by using grouping with attribute  `isStartNewPage="true"`, in your case on `$F{class}`

Example (insert under variable definition):

```
<group name="class" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{class}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="10"/>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="10"/>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
```

The grouping also give you the possibility to use two new bands (if you which), `groupHeader` (normally you put the class name in this one) and `groupFooter` (normally you put sum and counts of columns in this band)

Comment: I tried your answer but  page breaks after one row in my print.Suppose there are 45 students in class 1.This list of student from class 1 may go to second page  then print for class 2 should start for in new page i.e 3rd page.

Comment: Are they ordered by class or not?, this kind of grouping should do exactly what you are looking for..